# Are the automatobiles in ‘Sally’ supposed to have the Three Laws?

Tags: isaac-asimov, laws-of-robotics

In Isaac Asimov’s short story *Sally*, the main technology are self-driving “automatobiles” which are said to have “positronic” brains and intelligence, which would suggest that they are part of the positronic robot series. However, a major plot point is a modified bus killing the person who essentially tortured it and the story ends with the narrator fearing more car rebellions.

Obviously, killing a human being is the biggest First Law violation there could be. However, it is not clear to me which of the following is true of *Sally*;

1. The automatobiles’ positronic brains are *intended* to have the three laws, but the *Frankenstein* horrific modifications the villain did with transplanting and changing the brains created an “insane” car that lost compliance.
   Or:
2. Despite being a story about positronic artificial intelligence by Asimov, it’s in a different universe to the main Three Laws positronic robot stories.

Which one best describes the automatobiles?

Answer (score 8):

In *The Complete Robot*, one of the various collections of Asimov's robot stories, he states in a prologue:

> You will note, by the way, that in these three stories, the concept of Robot-as-Pathos is clearly marked. You may also notice, however, that in "Sally" there seems to be no hint of the Three Laws and that there is more than a hint of Robot-as-Menace. Well, if I want to do that once in a while, I can, I suppose. Who's there to stop me?

So he did not directly state that the three laws don't exist in the story, but he does note their absence.

Answer (score 3):

Not all of Asimov's robot stories share the same universe. For example, *Let's Get Together* features robots that deliberatly explode to kill people, even though they have positronic brains. Asimov used the term "positronic brain" simply because it sounded futuristic (see [What is the Positronic brain coined by Asimov?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/430/what-is-the-positronic-brain-coined-by-asimov)).

Similarly, a device called "neuronic whip" appears in several Asimov stories that are otherwise unrelated.